# What is this class in my Spark UI heap dump?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I’m trying to debug a Spark job that’s running out of memory. I see in the heap dump that the most allocated object is a “[B”. I assume this is related to Scala, perhaps generated classes, but do not recognize it and don’t get amazing results from Googling “[B class scala”

Comment: This is actually related to Java. This is a string generated from the JVM for and array of bytes. "[" means array and B means byte...

Comment: Don't see any reason for downvote. It's really nontrivial to google for things like `[B` , `B-]` or `:-P` if one doesn't know what one is looking for.